# Mailchimp marketing API "Your campaign is not ready to send" missing content field

Tags: node.js, email, mailchimp

I am new to both node.js and mailchimp api I am trying to create a campaign through api but "CONTENT"  field is not getting selected from the campaign.

which parameters should I pass to the create campaign api to get that content field selected.

Comment: Please provide which API you are calling and what data you are passing

Comment: Thanks for reply but the issue is solved I am able to generate content

Answer (score 0):

Create the campaign, then do a separate call to add the content `(PUT campaigns/{campaign id}/content)` then send